# Enable ''-enable-kvm" flag by default

Tags: qemu, kvm

My laptop support hardware virtualization & enabled in bios & i am trying to compile qemu from source. So Is it possible to compile qemu in a way that i do not enter "-enable-kvm" flage from command line every time?

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing configure --disable-tcg, which will disable the CPU emulation entirely (this only works for some target architectures like x86 at the moment). Then I think QEMU will default to KVM as the only available accelerator.

Alternatively if you rename your executable to something whose name ends with "kvm" then QEMU will default to the KVM accelerator rather than TCG. (I think a hardlink or maybe even a symlink to the binary will also work as well as simply renaming it, but haven't tested this.)

Comment: I think renaming the binary file solved the problem. I will compile qemu with "--disable-tcg" flag in my spare time. Thanks.